# How i put css on message of Hibernate validator anotation message of spring project

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, hibernate-validator

In my model class have the code using anottation of hibernate validator:

```
@Size(min = 2, message = "Mínimo 2 caracteres")
private String nome;
@Size(min = 5, message = "Mínimo 5 caracteres")
private String descricao;
```

In my jsp page the message below my input, but I wanted to put this message bootstrap class.
how do I handle this message anottation in the css?
thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a CSS class to the Spring tag that is actually displaying a the error like this:

`<sf:errors path="nome" cssClass="errortext" />`

Then define `.errortext` in your CSS file and set your styling from there.